# What does this mean in ssh config: "HostName %h"?

Tags: ssh, configuration

I have an ssh config file with something like this that I am not understanding.

```
Host my_alias
    HostName me@myserver.com
    HostName %h
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p me2.myserver.com
```

I thought %h stood for Hostname. What is the meaning of `HostName %h`?

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use `Hostname %h` like

```
Host my-*
    Hostname %h.site.dom
```

which would expand any host starting with `my-` (e.g. `my-test`) to the FQDN (e.g. `my-test.site.dom`)

`Hostname %h` on it's own won't do anything.

As you also define `HostName me@myserver.com` first (and ssh_config says "For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used.") the entry will be ignored.